# Cannot read property '0' of undefined for File Upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am having issues submitting my form to PHP > SQL using Jquery 3.1.1 and AJAX. It keeps giving me the error "Cannot read property "0" undefined". I have searched around here and the web for solutions, and tried them but the error persists.

I appreciate your help.

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
                $('.aulform').submit(function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              var form = new FormData();
              var title = $('.lesson-title');
              var description = $('.lesson-description');
              var category = $('.lesson-category');
              var tags = $('.lesson-tags');
              var post_files = this.files[0];

              console.log(post_files);

              var name = post_files.name;
              var type = post_files.type;
              var size = post_files.size;

                    form.append("audio_lesson", file);    
                    form.append("title", title.val());
                    form.append("description", description.val());
                    form.append("category", category.val());
                    form.append("tags", tags.val());
                    form.append("post_files", post_files);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: DIR+"/upload.php",
                        dataType: "text", 
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        data: form,
                        type: "POST",

                        });
                        }
                    });
                });

}(jQuery));
```

and my HTML looks like this:

```
<form class="aulform"  action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return false">
            <input class="create_post lesson-title" name="lesson-title" type="text" /><br/>
                <input type="file" class="custom-file-input audio-file" name="file[]" id="audioUploadInput" onChange="uploadOnChange(this)" accept="mp3">
            <div>
                <span class="fname_left">File Selected:</span>
                <input type="text" name="" class="fname_right" id="upload-filename" readonly>
            </div>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                function uploadOnChange(e) {
                  var filename = e.value;
                  var lastIndex = filename.lastIndexOf("\\");
                  if (lastIndex >= 0 ) {
                      filename = filename.substring(lastIndex + 1);
                  }
                  document.getElementById("upload-filename").value = filename;
                }
            </script>
            <textarea class="create_post lesson-description" name="lesson-description" type="text" ></textarea><br/>
            <input class="create_post lesson-category" name="lesson-category" type="text"/><br/>
            <input class="create_post lesson-tags" name="lesson-tags" type="text"/><br/>
<input  class="pri_btn aud_submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

I need the file and data to submit to the PHP and processed from there. Except the file and data does not reach that far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line that is erroring is `this.files[0]`, its because `this.files` is empty.

More than likely you want to reference the file input and not the form itself:

`$('.custom-file-input').get(0).files` and not `this.files` (which inside the `.submit()` event references the form)

You should read how to properly fetch the files using `new FormData`.

more information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

Comment: Thank you. This solution has worked. I simply added the `.get(0).` and it worked. I can now retrieve the file object.